# flask sqlalchemy column constraint for positive integer

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

how can i define a column as a positive integer using flask sqlalchemy?

i am hoping the answer would look something like this:

```
class City(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    population = db.Column(db.Integer, positive=True)
    def __init__(self,population):
        self.population = population
```

however, this class definition will throw an error b/c sqlalchemy does not know about a 'positive' argument.

i could raise an exception if an object is instantiated with a negative value for the population. but i don't know how to ensure that the population remains positive after an update.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

unfortunately, on the python side, sqlalchemy does its best to stay out of the way; there's no 'special sqlalchemy' way to express that the instance attribute must satisfy some constraint:

```
>>> class Foo(Base):
...     __tablename__ = 'foo'
...     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
...     bar = Column(Integer)
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar = "not a number!"
>>> f.bar
'not a number!'
```

If you tried to commit this object, sqlalchey *would* complain because it doesn't know how to render the supplied python value as SQL for the column type `Integer`.

If that's not what you're looking for, you just want to make sure that bad data doesn't reach the database, then you need a `Check` Constraint.

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar = Column(Integer)
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint(bar >= 0, name='check_bar_positive'),
        {})
```

Comment: `bar >= 0` should be called `check_bar_non_negative`. For `check_bar_positive` I would expect `bar > 0`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but for what it's worth, my approach was to use [marshmallow](http://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (de/serialization and data validation library) to validate input data.

Create the schema to your model as such:

```
from marshmallow import validate, fields, Schema

... 

class CitySchema(Schema):
    population = fields.Integer(validate=validate.Range(min=0, max=<your max value>))
```

Then use your schema to serialize/deserialize the data when appropriate:

```
... 
city_data = {...} # your city's data (dict)
city_schema = CitySchema()
deserialized_city, validation_errors = city_schema.load(city_data) # validation done at deserialization
...
```

The advantage of using a de/serialization library is that you can enforce all your data integrity rules in one place

Comment: While this is an option and, imho, works great as a supplement, it's better to define data constraints at the data layer so that no bad data manages to leak in by some other means. ie, an error with a validation, you've written a script to manually create data, various other corner cases.