# How to find the column name when using a custom column type in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to define my own column type in sqlalchemy:

```
class NonNegativeInt(TypeDecorator):
    impl = Integer

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            if not isinstance(value, int) or value < 0:
                raise TypeError('Expect non-negative integer, find %s instead.' % value)
        return value

class Game(Model):
    score = Column(NonNegativeInt, default=0)
```

When I try to bind a negative integer to a NonNegativeInt column, e.g. score, it raises an error as expected:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (exceptions.TypeError) Expect non-negative integer, find -1 instead.
```

However, it dose not specify the name of the column, therefore it is not easy to debug when there are a lot of columns. When using the original Integer type, I got more specific error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1366, u"Incorrect integer value: 'aaaa' for column 'score' at row 1")
```

How can I find the name of the column with error (e.g. score)? Moreover, is it possible to raise error when assigning a wrong value: `game.score = -1`, instead of when committing?

Comment: I hope this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225998/flask-sqlalchemy-column-constraint-for-positive-integer

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks. This method can check the constraints, but it is not what I want.

Comment: I'm currently dealing with the *exact* same issue where I see the error message logged, but I don't see clearly which column is affected. Stapping through the debugger, it looks to me that this is not possible in the current version of SA (`1.1.15`)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the `inspect` module. As it uses the inspect module it might not be very robust against SA upgrades (as mentioned in the docstring).

This code assumes that the value is available as variable `key` two stack-levels above `TypeDecorator.process_bind_param` (hence the index `[3]` in `get_column_name`). If either the stack depth or the variable name changes inside SA, this code will break, which is why it uses a "bare except". However, the exception will be logged as `DEBUG` message including the stack-trace, so it should remain debuggable.

I do however think that is is fairly unlikely that that portion of SA will change.

```
import logging

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def get_column_name() -> str:
    """
    Tries to determine the field/column-name from inside a TypeDecorator
    method.

    This is done by inspecting the current Python stack and may not always work
    and is not guaranteed to survive SQLAlchemy upgrades. In that case, it will
    return ``"<unknown>"`` as value so you should not use this for any other
    use-case than debugging or logging!
    """
    from inspect import getmembers, getouterframes, currentframe
    frame = currentframe()
    column_name = '<unknown>'
    try:
        target_frame = getouterframes(frame)[3]
        frame_locals = dict(getmembers(target_frame))['frame'].f_locals
        column_name = frame_locals['key']
    except:  # pylint: disable=bare-except
        LOG.debug('Unable to retrieve the column name', exc_info=True)
    return column_name
```

This function can then be used inside the `TypeDecorator`:

```
class NonNegativeInt(TypeDecorator):
    impl = Integer

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        column = get_column_name()
        if value is not None:
            if not isinstance(value, int) or value < 0:
                raise TypeError('Expect non-negative integer in column %r, find %s instead.' % (column, value))
        return value
```